# 2D Array sum all numbers in a row except for the diagonal index

Tags: java, arrays

I was wrecking my brain for a while now and finally gave up.

Say, this is my array:

```
   int[][] arr =   {{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5},
                    {2, 36, 1, 2, 1},
                    {0, 0, 9, 0, 3},
                    {4, 4, 4, 225, 3},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 16}};
```

I need to calculate the sum of all of the numbers except for the `arr[i][i]` and then compare it's power of two to the said number.

For example, `144` is the `arr[0][0]` in the first loop. I need to take `(2 + 3 + 2 + 5)^2` and check if it's equal to `144` (it is). I was happy when I did it with the first row, but then got stuck on idea of taking every now except the `arr[i][i]` number, which in the second row is `36`.

I got nothing until now, only wrong assumptions. I'm still learning 2D arrays but the subject doesn't sit well.

```java
public class TwoDArray {

    public static void SquareNum(final int[][] arr) {
    double sqaureSum = 0;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr[i].length - 1; i++) {
        total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            }
            ???
        }
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int[][] arr =   {{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5},
                            {2, 36, 1, 2, 1},
                            {0, 0, 9, 0, 3},
                            {4, 4, 4, 225, 3},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 16}};
    SquareNum(arr);
    }
}
```

Any leads on how I can achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks good so far. A good next step would be something like `total += arr[i][j];`

Comment: @Jaybird I wrote that before just to see what it gives. I thought it gave me a lead on how to proceed, but my brain doesn't get it. It sums up each row individually. How do I make it output the info I need at the end of each row?

Comment: Once the inner loop has calculated the row total, you can perform your check: `Math.pow(total - arr[i][i], 2) == arr[i][i]`

Comment: Each time you start a row (a new i), you throw away all you have accumulated and reset the total to 0. You may want to have more than one "total" variable if you want to get the individual row totals. Also, if you don't want to include the diagonals, do an if test to see if i == j before allowing the add to occur.

Comment: @Jaybird Thanks! Looks like it works, but I'm trying to understand the logic: At the end of each row, I calculated the total of that row. Then, I took that total, subtracted the arr[i][i] number, then put everything to the power of two, and if that resulted in that same arr[i][i] then I found what I'm looking for? I hope I understood it correctly. Also, how would you suggest I output this? Like "The row numbers where the if is true is: input here"

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure how to continue the after this check though. Assuming i==j, how do I tell it: "dont add it up"?

Comment: @Jaybird I appreciate your help! How can I mark it as resolved and give you the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code with my suggestions in the comments above added. I've also shown how I'd do the output as you described.

```
class TwoDArray {

    public static void SquareNum(final int[][] arr) {
        String output = "The row numbers where the condition is true are: ";
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[i].length; i++) {
            total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                total += arr[i][j];
            }
            double squareSum = Math.pow(total - arr[i][i], 2);
            if (squareSum == arr[i][i])
            {
                output += i + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int[][] arr =   {{ 144, 2, 3, 2, 5},
                {2, 36, 1, 2, 1},
                {0, 0, 9, 0, 3},
                {4, 4, 4, 225, 3},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 16}};
        SquareNum(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe`i < arr[i].length - 1` in the first `for` loop should be `i < arr.length`. Currently you're not considering the last row.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense @SirRaffleBuffle, I'll edit accordingly